# How to use matches method properly?

Tags: java

I'm wanting to know how to use the String method `matches()` properly as well as efficiently. I also came across a "*problem*", when I was using `String.matches()`. I am creating a `class` where the *constructor parameter* needs to meet certain conditions.

**Example:**

```
if (String.matches(".*\\d+.*" + "/" + ".*\\d+,*")
   // do something 
else
  // throw something
```

It blocks only one out of the four of the problems.

**Blocks:**

```
String test1 = "1/2a;
```

**Doesn't block:**

```
String test2 = "a1/2";
String test3 = "1a/2";
String test4 = "1/a2";
```

I'm pretty sure it's an error on my part. And I don't want to use another `if` statement, or something "*clunky*", want to *try* to keep everything readable. I have read on how to check a `String` for letters, e.g `[a-zA-Z]`.

If I missed anything let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the pattern? What do you want to accept? This site might prove useful when working with regex: https://regexr.com/

Comment: I want to except only a `String` in the form of: "some number / some other number".  So basically in the form of a fraction. Sorry, typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a pattern that will match only strings in format `[integer]/[integer]` try this for the pattern: `"^[0-9]+\/[0-9]+$"`

make sure the backslash is escaped in the string(possibly: `"^[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+$"`)

You can try it here: http://regexr.com/3h41b